# No BoundService Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

I have created a mobile game in Unity and I am currently trying to get Google Play Services working with it so I can have leaderboards. I have got it building and running on android but when it goes to log in, I get the same error over and over again on the android monitor, using Logcat.

These are the errors:

> 01-23 13:16:09.590: E/BoundService(5473): No such BoundService for action: com.google.android.gms.games.service.START
>
> 01-23 13:16:09.679: E/BoundService(5473): No such BoundService for action: com.google.android.gms.auth.APP_CERT

I dont really know much about BoundServices and what they are, but is it not finding these parts to run or is there some permissions which aren't allowing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by publishing game in play services or alternatievely you could add test accounts in google play console.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue.